# v-model for dynamically generated checkboxes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Here is my fiddle : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/az9hge7u/)

```
 modules: [{
      moduleName: "Module ABC",
      id: 1,
      actions: [{
        actionName: "addbrand",
        id: 1,
        permissions: [{
          permissionName: "read",
          "id": 1,
          "value": true
        }, {
          permissionName: "write",
          "id": 2,
          "value": true
        }, {
          permissionName: "execute",
          "id": 1,
          "value": false
        }]
}]
```

Checkboxes are dynamically generated iterating over "modules" array in data object. But I am finding it difficult to assign v-model and capture the checked values for the corresponding "action" for its respective "module"'

How do I do this?

```
<div v-for="module in modules"><b>{{ module.moduleName }}</b>
    <div v-for="action in module.actions">{{ action.actionName }}
      <div v-for="permission in action.permissions">
        <input type="checkbox"> {{ permission.permissionName }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure having nesting more than 2 `v-for` is a good idea. But you can create an `index` in v-for as: `<p v-for='(foo, index) in array'` and use the index to track changes.

In you case you do something like this  https://jsfiddle.net/samayo/az9hge7u/5/

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    modules: [{
      moduleName: "Module ABC",
      id: 1,
      actions: [{
        actionName: "addbrand",
        id: 1,
        permissions: [{
          permissionName: "read",
          "id": 1,
          "value": true
        }, {
          permissionName: "write",
          "id": 2,
          "value": true
        }, {
          permissionName: "execute",
          "id": 1,
          "value": false
        }]
      }, {
        actionName: "addproduct",
        id: 2,
        permissions: [{
          permissionName: "read",
          id: 1,
          value: true
        }, {
          permissionName: "write",
          id: 2,
          value: true
        }, {
          permissionName: "execute",
          id: 1,
          value: false
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      moduleName: "Module PQR",
      id: 2,
      actions: [{
        actionName: "addrules",
        id: 3,
        permissions: [{
          permissionName: "read",
          id: 1,
          value: true
        }, {
          permissionName: "write",
          id: 2,
          value: true
        }, {
          permissionName: "execute",
          id: 1,
          value: false
        }]
      }, {
        actionName: "addactions",
        id: 4,
        permissions: [{
          permissionName: "read",
          id: 1,
          value: true
        }, {
          permissionName: "write",
          id: 2,
          value: true
        }, {
          permissionName: "execute",
          id: 1,
          value: false
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.3/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(module, moduleIndex) in modules"><b>{{ module.moduleName }}</b>
    <div v-for="(action, actionIndex) in module.actions">{{ action.actionName }}
      <div v-for="(permission, permIndex) in action.permissions">
        <input type="checkbox" v-model='modules[moduleIndex].actions[actionIndex].permissions[permIndex].value'> {{ permission.permissionName }} - {{modules[moduleIndex].actions[actionIndex].permissions[permIndex].value}}
      </div>    
    </div> <hr>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi I was looking for capturing the details once checked, something like this : If read write are checked for ADD BRAND, write exceute are checked for ADD RULES....modules:[{moduleABC : { addbrand : permissions : {read, write} }},{modulePQR : { addrules : permissions : {write,execute} }}] How to achieve this please?

Comment: If i understand the question. Maybe once checked use only `modules[moduleIndex]` part or `modules[moduleIndex].action` to get the actions or `modules[moduleIndex].actions[actionIndex]` which action and so on

Comment: That's right. Thanks so much. I have accepted your answer. Could you please look into this? https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/c7amyx6o/

Comment: thanks, I'm looking at it ... is something wrong? it looks ok to me

Comment: If you could look at the fiddle now, I am displaying only those actions whose chosen permissions are true. How do I create a JSON or v-model to show the same?

Comment: Err.. sorry but I don't understand you question. the code is working well, it shows you the true and false values. what is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/srinivassunkari/t2fjzLpn/29/

1 Because of mutation no need to use the index to update the values of permission 'value'

2 When you use v-model it updates the value of the permission in the module.action.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="module in modules"><b>{{ module.moduleName }}</b>
        <div v-for="action in module.actions">{{ action.actionName }}
            <div v-for="permission in action.permissions">
                <input type="checkbox" v-model="permission.value">
                {{ permission.permissionName }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
<script>

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            modules: [{
                moduleName: "Module ABC",
                id: 1,
                actions: [{
                    actionName: "addbrand",
                    id: 1,
                    permissions: [{
                        permissionName: "read",
                        "id": 1,
                        "value": true
                    }, {
                        permissionName: "write",
                        "id": 2,
                        "value": true
                    }, {
                        permissionName: "execute",
                        "id": 1,
                        "value": false
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }
    },
    // for understanding purpose added no need to consider this...
    watch: {
        modules: {
            deep: true,
            handler(modules) {
                console.log('modules', modules)
            }
        }
    }
})
</script>
```